# how to make android layout to be same when we rotate screen

Tags: android, orientation

I have two recyclerview in my xml when we change orientation or rotate screen the layout changes how to make the layout to be the same instead of changing layout

Comment: By default, it will be the same layout. If the layout is changing, it is because you created multiple versions of the same layout (e.g., in `res/layout/` and `res/layout-land/`). You might consider editing your question to provide a [mcve], including providing links to screenshots illustrating what you are seeing.

Comment: Layout is same as in xml but i want the same size when i rotate but when i rotate the screen my second recycler view is going down and not showing completely as it is showing in portrait

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it divide your screen into two parts both portrait and landscape mode

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want the size of my layout should be same in both. your answer is for not restarting the activity when i change..

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are asking. But for what i have understood.

1. Use LinearLayout, inside it have two recyclerview and give height based on weight property = .5 each;
   LIKE THIS ::

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
   ```
2. Make a landscape version of that layout and do the same as told above. Easiest way to do this, is to go to GUI screen of xml and to the right of language tab, is Layout Variats tab- select create landscape variation.

Comment: Inside linearlayout i took recyclerviews but how to give height based on weight property i didn't understand.